# How to parse or assign variables in the field VALUE of a SQL query statement in python?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

**Overall the concept is  storing the username, password in the database performing a SQL query after  Tkinter Button is pressed**.
For which I have  **insert.py**  and  **login.py**. In insert.py code is like below :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'kuis');
a= 14
b=16

a="john"
b="snow"

with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        #    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE admin_details(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
        #                Name VARCHAR(25))")
        ##cur.execute("INSERT INTO admin_details(username, password)  VALUES('%s','%s' )" %(a,b))
```

Which stores the valuse username:14 and password:16 in the admin_details table after the program is started.(Not after pressing the button login but only after running the code)
But My concern here is when I give a character a="john" and b="snow" , I define value as  VALUES('%s', '%s')" %('a','b') but I get the error i.e.

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Also I tried this method by assigning c= ['a','b'] as a tuple but still the error is same.

**My First concern is how to assign a character or string in the SQL query's VALUE ?**

Another I have **login.py** which consists of Two Tkinter Entry Username and password with its attribute StringVar for username as **uname** and password as **pword** 
    from Tkinter import *
    root = Tk()

```
test=StringVar()

label1=Label(root,text='Username').grid()
entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=uname)
entry1.grid()

label2=Label(root,text='Password').grid()
entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=pword)
entry2.grid()

#print test
button_submit= Button(root, text = 'Login').grid()       
root.mainloop()
```

This file creates the field to enter username and password. 
Now coming to the point as a newbie I have no Idea about following techniques:

1. parsing the values uname and pword only after the button is pressed.
2. in the uname and pword field where the recent values are manually assigned as john and john1, I donot have idea how to assign variables uname and pword in those field.
3. Also I have no idea about validating if the entered values is correct in the database so that I can go to the next page.

PS: Above questions are asked because I am unable to find the solution in the internet with my skill and knowledge about python and Tkinter.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you should NOT be storing passwords in clear text. You should be using a hash with salt. Also, you tagged both mysql and sql-server. You should only tag what is relevant and honestly this doesn't really have much of anything to do with the database.

Comment: @SeanLange How is 'hash with salt' implemented?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=hash+with+salt&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: That topic is way beyond the scope of this forum. The basic gist is that you don't want your passwords stored. Consider what happens when there is a data breach.

Comment: I am aware about the data breach, just as a newbie I had no idea of implementing it in python. And I am working on it. If you have any suggestions for rest of my queries above ,it is highly appreciated